# Zlib compression header fails checksum with error -3

Tags: python, compression, png, zlib, deflate

I'm trying to write my own deflate implementation in `python` with Fixed Huffman. When I pack the image back into the .png file nothing is being displayed in a regular image viewer. Each chunk header is formed according to the specification from the RFC-1950.
I have used pngcheck to find out why the image wasn't displaying anything and got these 2 messages back:

> zlib: compression header fails checksum
>
> zlib: inflate_error = -3

For the Adler32 value I calculated it like `zlib.adler32(bytearray(scanline))`. One more thing that confuses me is the endianness of the compressed stream and I'm not entirely sure on how to pack the fixed Huffman code bits inside the bytes, I know that it is specified in RFC-1951.

```
#zLibHeaderArray = bytearray([CMF,FLG])
zLibHeaderArray = bytearray([78,1])
outputPNG.write(zLibHeaderArray)

#First three bits per block
outputBitStream = ba.bitarray(endian = 'big')

if(isLast != 1):
    outputBitStream += ba.bitarray('001')
else:
    outputBitStream += ba.bitarray('101')

#-- here i transform the input scanline with lz77 and huffman and load it into the big endian bitarray

outputBitStream += ba.bitarray(getHuffman(256,huffman))
outputBitStream.tofile(outputPNG)
#Adler32 Checksum

adler32Value = zlib.adler32(bytearray(scanline))
a1, a2, a3, a4 = (adler32Value & 0xFFFFFFFF).to_bytes(4, 'big')

adler32Array = bytearray([a1,a2,a3,a4])
outputPNG.write(adler32Array)
```

The CRC isn't causing errors for the iDAT chunk so my best guess is the Adler32 checksum.

Comment: "scanline" is the uncompressed data which i got by applying the filter + appending the filter value to the filtered pixels

Comment: You are right, I missed that! But I do hope you constructed this `scanline` correct. Mind you, even if you did not, it's not "the" answer, as zlib doesn't care and ought to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should carefully read error messages. "compression header fails checksum" indicates that it is the zlib *header* that is incorrect, not the trailer which is the Adler-32. That two-byte header includes a five-bit check value that is not properly set in your stream. (Or maybe you forgot the header completely.)